# PHP and HTML Undefined Index on file upload

Tags: php, html, indexing, undefined

Here is my HTML Code

```
 <HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Upload a File</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<H1>Upload a File</H1>
<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="PHP3.php">
<strong>File to Upload:</strong><br>
<INPUT TYPE="file" NAME="txt1" SIZE="50">
<P><INPUT TYPE="submit" NAME="submit" VALUE="Upload File"></P>
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

And here is my PHP Code

```
if ($_FILES['txt1'] != '')
{
    mkdir("C:/xampp/CIS64/"); //Creates the CIS64 directory
    $filename = "C:/xampp/CIS64/"; //Location of where the file will be
    copy($_FILES['txt1']['tmp_name'], $filename.$_FILES['txt1']['name']) or die("Couldn't copy the file."); //Copies the uploaded file to the CIS64 directory
}
else
{
    die("No input file specified"); //If the file doesn't open, close the program.
}
```

For some reason I get the error: "Undefined index: txt1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP3.php on line 11"
It was working before and all of a sudden it stopped working. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Check with

```
if (!empty($_FILES['txt1']))
```

because at the time when form is not posted there would be nothing like `$_POST['txt1']`

and `<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="PHP3.php">` should be `<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="PHP3.php" enctype="multipart-formdata">` for file uploading.

Comment: That's my problem! The form is not being posted after I upload my file. I'm thinking it is somewhere in my HTML code, but I see no errors.

Comment: Well it doesn't solve it. But it shows where the problem is at. I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: updated my answer. you missed `enctype` form property.

Answer (score 0):

1. form must have attribute 'enctype=multipart/form-data'
   Example: `<form action=PHP3.php method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>`
2. add strings to your "PHP3.php" such as `var_dump($_POST);` and `var_dump($_FILES);` and check what is inside - helps you to debug!
3. Location to save I set using `$location = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/myuploaddir/' . $filename;`